# Why is the output of this code gh?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void f(char**); 

int main() { 
    char *argv[] = { "ab", "cd", "ef", "gh", "ij", "kl" }; 

    f(argv); 
    return 0; 
} 



void f(char **p) { 
    char *t; 

    t = (p += sizeof(int))[-1]; 
    printf("%s\n", t); 
}
```

This is the code i have and the question is asking for the output. I am wondering why the output is gh. I assumed the the sizeof(int) would equal the number of elements in char which would make it 6 then minus 1 in terms of the "t" statement. I then printed the sizeof(int) and it gave me 4. I am just confused as why the sizeof(int) is 4 and not 6. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sizeof(int) would equal the number of elements in char` How did you possible come to that conclusion?

Comment: Hey, guess what `argc` is there for!!!!

Comment: I meant to mean that if it were just a string say "string" its would be the size of that string in bytes? Then i did further looking and correct me if im wrong but would it be 4 because it's calculating the size of the pointer to char which would be 4 bytes?

Comment: *confused as why the sizeof(int) is 4 and not 6* - Why? The sizeof an int is 4 bytes on the platform you're compiling on. I know of no current platform where the size of an int is 6 bytes; they're almost always a power of 2, and currently usually 4 bytes (32 bits) or 8 (64 bits).

Comment: ooooooh k thank you so much. When i was searching for an answer i was just getting conflicting answers. Makes more sense now. Thank you i just needed someone to clear it up for me. Now i feel foolish

Comment: this is also amusing since on older systems, like DOS, sizeof int would be 2, and in the future it may become 8; int is very misleading sizewise; which is when size matters, I prefer `#include <stdint.h>` for `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t` or it's `uintx_t` versions.

Comment: To be clear, `sizeof(int)` has nothing to do with `char *argv[] = { "ab", "cd", "ef", "gh", "ij", "kl" };`.  The `sizeof(int)` is independent of the `sizeof(some_pointer)` although they tend too be the half, x1 or x2 the other.

Answer (score 2):

Explanation for `t = (p += sizeof(int))[-1];`:

1. `p` which is a pointer is incremented by `sizeof(int)` elements. On your machine, `sizeof(int)` seems to be `4`.
2. `p` is a pointer to the fifth element, which is `"ij"`.
3. `[-1]` assigns `p` decremented by one element to `t`. `p` decremented by 1 means you are pointing to the pointer to `"gh"`. Oh, and there's a dereference operation going on here due to the square brackets.
4. print `t`.

Just to illustrate the third point, you may replace `f` with the following lines and check:

```
void f(char **p) { 
    char **t; 

    t = (p += sizeof(int)) - 1;
    printf("%s\n", *t); 
}
```

HTH.

Comment: I am not sure that I like "`[-1]` assigns `p` decremented by one element to `t`. I think that what you are getting at is that, according to the Standard, "`E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1) + (E2)))`." (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 6.5.2.1/2) So, `p[-1] == (*(p - 1))`, which is fine, so long as `p` does not point to the first element of the array. So, `t` is in fact assigned the value referenced by the pointer preceding `p`.

Comment: @DavidBowling "`t` is in fact assigned the value referenced by the pointer preceding `p`" - Brilliantly put. :)

Answer (score 0):

> I am just confused as why the sizeof(int) is 4 and not 6

Others have already given you the correct answer, so I'm just trying to help you bridge the gap from your assumption about `sizeof(int)`.

**sizeof** is a C operator (not function).  If you have a Linux or Mac available, **man operator** in a terminal will show you the whole list.  It yields the size of its operand, in bytes.  Unlike most operators, sizeof operates on a variable *or a type*.  When you say `sizeof(int)`, you're applying sizeof to the datatype `int`.  Unsurprisingly, the result is always the same, because in C every `int` in a program has the same size.  On your machine, that size is 4.

Taking that one step further, you can see that giving the name of a variable to sizeof is only a convenience.  The compiler resolves the name, finds its *type*, and gets the size of the type.

> char *argv[]

We can apply sizeof to your `argv` usefully to find out how many elements are in the array.  The whole array has a size, in bytes, of `sizeof(argv)`.  Each element -- because all elements in an array have the same size -- has the size, in bytes, of `sizeof(argv[0])`.  The number of elements, then, is `sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0])`.  You can even say,

```
enum { nargv = sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0]) };
```

because all the information is available at compile time.